# Unable get hidden service address

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I followed this post:

https://www.privex.io/articles/setup-tor-hidden-service-website/

to create a local lan website with ubuntu.

But After I configurated and restarted the tor service.

No hostname file was created.

I am now in China.

And some outgoing connections maybe blocked.

Is it a possible reason why I can't get the hostname?

How can I determine the reason why I can get the hostname?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach your server locally? 
You said that there is no hostname file created. Is there any key created? If isn't you probably screwed up try execute: "sudo tor" it will give you an error messages unlike if you run it as a service.

Can you try use tor as a proxy? (this can determine if your connection is censored)